# If $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ complex matrix and some power of $A$ is diagonal, then $A$ can be diagonalized

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove or provide a counter-example: If $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ complex matrix and some power of $A$ is diagonal, then $A$ can be diagonalized.

If $A^n$ is a diagonal matrix, then clearly $A^{n-1}=I$. We can look at it this way: $A^s A A^{n-1-s}=A^n$, which is diagonal, leading to the conclusion that $I=A^sA^{n-1-s}=A^{n-1}$. Now if $A^{n-1}$ is $I$, and $A^n$ is a diagonal, clearly $A$ is also diagonal. Hence proved.

Is the proof given above correct?

Comment: The matrix $\operatorname{diag}(1,2)^n$ is diagonal for all $n$, but only for $n=0$ is it the identity?

Comment: "If $A^n$ is a diagonal matrix, then clearly $A^{n−1}=I$", Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is true in any algebraically closed field $K$ if $n$ does not divide the characteristic of $K$, not only in $\mathbf C$. Here is why:

$A^n$ is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial $P(x)$ has only simple (nonzero) roots. Let $(\lambda_1, \dots,\lambda_r)$ be the eigenvalues of $A^n$; we can write: 
$$P(x)=(x-\lambda_1)\dotsm(x-\lambda_r).$$
Set $Q(x)=P(x^n)$. By definition of the minimal polynomial, $Q(A)=P(A^n)=0$, and
$$Q(x)=(x^n-\lambda_1)\dotsm(x^n-\lambda_r)$$ 
also has only simple roots.

Now the minimal polynomial of $A$ is a divisor of $Q$, thus it has only simple roots. This proves $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: Not in any algebraically closed field. The characteristic must not divide $n$, since $x^n-a$ is not separable if the characteristic divides $n$.

Comment: @MooS: Forgot that detail, as the O.P. mentioned only $\mathbf C$. I'll add it. Thanks for pointing it.